# DDK preprocessor directives

Tags: preprocessor, cpu-architecture, wdk

Does the DDK's build environments pass preprocessor defines to code to specify x86/ia64/x64 for the code to use with `#ifdef`, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've seen it does not.

However, when setting up your makefile, make `i385`, `amd64` and `ia64` directories and store your separate code files in those.

Then, in your sources file, use the `I386_SOURCES=`, `AMD64_SOURCES=` and `IA64_SOURCES=` vars, respectively, to specify the source files.

This works with .asm files, and *should* work with all other .c files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Look at [Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Also you can see a lot of such statements in DDK include files:

```
#if defined(_M_MRX000) || defined(_M_ALPHA) || defined(_M_PPC) || defined(_M_IA64) || defined(_M_AMD64)
#define UNALIGNED __unaligned
#if defined(_WIN64)
#define UNALIGNED64 __unaligned
#else
#define UNALIGNED64
#endif
#else
#define UNALIGNED
#define UNALIGNED64
#endif
```